# How to import global CA certificate programatically in Android 4.X?

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

Our application use http/https to connect its REST server. All works just fine before we switched to https. `Min SDK version = 14`. IOS version works without any problem.

Here is the `openssl s_client -connect test_server.ru:443` output:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=test_server.ru
   i:/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Domain Validated SSL/CN=thawte DV SSL CA - G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Domain Validated SSL/CN=thawte DV SSL CA - G2
   i:/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA
   i:/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA
```

Android 4-5 Chrome show site certificate as invalid (red and crossed). Application catch exception: "Trust anchor for certification path not found"

So I added both keys to asset folder and made quick static class to use these keys:

```
public class CustomTrustCA {
    private static SSLContext mSSLContext = null;

    public static SSLSocketFactory getInstance() {
        if (mSSLContext == null && Init() == null) return null;
        return mSSLContext.getSocketFactory();
    }

    public static SSLContext Init() {
        Certificate ca = null;
        Certificate ca2 = null;
        InputStream caInput = null;
        InputStream caInput2 = null;
        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = null;
        mSSLContext = null;

        //noinspection TryFinallyCanBeTryWithResources
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            caInput = Application.AppContext.getAssets().open("thawte.cer");
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            caInput2 = Application.AppContext.getAssets().open("thawte2.cer");
            ca2 = cf.generateCertificate(caInput2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.Exception(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (caInput != null) caInput.close();
                if (caInput2 != null) caInput2.close();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }

        if (ca == null) return null;
        if (ca2 == null) return null;
        try {
            // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca2", ca2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.Exception(e);
        }

        try {
            // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.Exception(e);
        }

        if (tmf == null) return null;
        try {
            // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
            mSSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            mSSLContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.Exception(e);
        }

        return mSSLContext;
    }
}
```

Then I added this to low-level http code:

```
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) full_url.openConnection();
SSLSocketFactory instance = CustomTrustCA.getInstance();
if (instance != null) urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(instance);
```

This fixed things, but Universal Image Loader breaks too, so I wrote some code to fix it (custom image downloader class):

```
public class SecureImageDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader {
    public static final String TAG = SecureImageDownloader.class.getName();


    public SecureImageDownloader(Context context, int connectTimeout, int readTimeout) {
        super(context, connectTimeout, readTimeout);
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream getStreamFromNetwork(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(imageUri);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Logger.Exception(e);
        }
        HttpURLConnection http = null;
        if (url == null) return null;

        if (Scheme.ofUri(imageUri) == Scheme.HTTPS) {
            HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            https.setSSLSocketFactory(CustomTrustCA.getInstance());
            http = https;
            http.connect();
        } else {
            http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        }

        http.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        http.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        return new FlushedInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(http.getInputStream()));
    }
}
```

Ok. Main code now works. UIL works too... But...

**Finally I found that DownloadManager & Intent.ACTION_VIEW for attachments stops working too** (application pass them https url!), but can't figure out how to fix them. Here is my code:

```
if (isNotEmpty(documentUri)) {
    DownloadManager.Request downloadReq = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(documentUri));
    downloadReq.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, attachment.Name());
    downloadReq.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    downloadReq.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) Application.AppContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    dm.enqueue(downloadReq);
}
```

Is there any way to add system-wide CA certificate using code (i.e. start some settings intent or something else)?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote simple lib [ssl-utils-android](https://github.com/mklimek/ssl-utils-android) to load particular certificate from assets like that:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SslUtils.getSslContextForCertificateFile(context, "BPClass2RootCA-sha2.cer");
```

You can read more about it on [my blog post](https://mklimek.github.io/trust-specific-certificate-on-jvm/).

Edit:
Load your own instance of http client to Universal Image Loader like:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
    ...
    .imageDownloader(new HttpClientImageDownloader(context, yourHttpClient))
    ...
    .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

I haven't ever use UIL. Hope it will work.

Comment: My code do this allready, but i can't figure out how to change sslcontext of DownloadManager and Intent.ACTION_VIEW.....

Comment: To make  Universal Image Loader works you have to add CA also to it because it uses another instance of HTTP client.

Comment: Currently UIL allready fixed (see code above). I have problems with external intents (downloader and ACTION_VIEW) only and have no ideas how to fix them...

Comment: I answered the question from the subject. I don't see how `Intent` can somehow break CA things. They are totally unrelated.

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to ask how to import CA certificate globally... About download mansger and action_view - my application use them to download attachments and show attached pictures. Both DownloadManager and Intent.ACTION_VIEW use HTTPS url provided by application to download data. And they failed to do this because of certs. So download attaches/view attaches not working...

Comment: You cannot add it globally to the system through the app. You can do that from the system settings only. What's you can do is to use only one instance of HTTP client and use it everywhere in the app with dynamically loaded CA. Having only one instance of HTTP client sounds reasonable.

Comment: So i have to write my own downloader with notifications, girls and chess?

Comment: No, just pass your instance of http client to it. I hope it allow to do that. I edited my answer.

Comment: Download manager doesn't allow to pass http client or SSLSocketFactory - it is external application :(

Comment: You can do this. Check my answer again.

Comment: Ehm... Its looks like there is some confusion between universal image loader and android.app.DownloadManager. I added some code lines to bottom of question.

Comment: You don't have to use it. Use HTTP client to download files.

Comment: Ok. I understand your position, but can't accept it. I don't think it is normal when every android application implement its own downloader, image viewer, photo camera, etc...

Comment: No. It's not normal when you want to trust CA which isn't trusted by the system. It's a hack. This is why you should have custom HTTP client.